# How to call static file handler from HTTP handler in IIS7 and ASP.NET 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I create custom HTTP handler for auto generating file and I want to tell IIS7 to serve current request like normal static file because I need to use IIS and web.config file to control compression setting and any other HTTP header of current requested file.

I know. there is an internal class called [StaticFileHandler][1] in ASP.net. But I cannot access it. Or you have any other way to work like this.  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404287.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be pretty easy to replicate StaticFileHandler

1. Download Reflector
2. Open System.Web
3. Search for StaticFileHandler
4. Open method ProcessRequestInternal()
5. Open method SendFile()

Copy the bits you need, basically it boils down to this method:

```
context.Response.TransmitFile(physicalPath, offset, length);
```

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](http://sticklebackplastic.com/post/2006/10/09/The-continuing-saga-of-StaticFileHandler-meet-DefaultHttpHandler.aspx) describes when the StaticFileHandler will be used:

> if you haven't modified any **headers** (such as caching) and you haven't already written something to the **response stream**, and the response stream doesn't have a **filter** (such as compression) and you're running **in-process** in IIS6 then the request is passed back to IIS for processing.

As far as I've tested this is also true for IIS7. I'm not exactly sure how, but if you don't handle a certain request in your own handler it should get passed on to IIS. Can anyone confirm that?

At least, following the above hints worked for my static files.